# Meaning of DO-254 Standard

Tags: standard

I could not find the meaning of DO-254 which is a military standard (not component package). Do you know that the expansion of DO letters?

Comment: Are you referring to the diode package?

Comment: It's a safety of flight standard for hardware (airborne electronics)

Comment: *complex hardware*

Answer (score 4):

> ***DO***
>
> **Document**, from RTCA

[source](https://www.mentor.com/solutions/do-254/glossary/dg)

Comment: Compare to TO-220...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: Nope. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DO-254

Comment: Oh, I see -- since this was EE.SE I was assuming someone was scratching their head over a package number...:P

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: Me too, until I double-checked.